# How to create a select list that contains url links

Tags: 7, nodes

This is probably a very noob question but here it is none the less. I want to create a select list that contains the names of places around the world. When the user clicks on a name, it uses a hidden url to go to that place. So what the user sees is a normal select list of place names (not links), when they select an item then they are taken to that page.

On the manage field tab of the node that this is implemented on, I tried creating a select element with the following options:

```
 http://www.australia.com|Australia
 http://www.germany.com|Germany
```

But this doesn't work. What do I need to do to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With views you van create jump menu's: http://nodeone.se/en/learn-views-with-nodeone-part-18-jump-menu

You can use that view as a block on your page.

If you want to use it between your other fields, you can use the module https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield. Add a field of type viewfield on your content type, choose the view you created earlier and pass the nid as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried implementing the jump-menu view but that isn't working. When I set the title as link, it thinks that it is an internal link. The url generated is mywebsite.com/australia instead of http://www.australia.com. Do you know how to fix this so it works properly?

Comment: When inputting the links, add http:// in front. Then it will be recognized as external.

Comment: I found my error. I missed the step of selecting the url and have not being displayed. It all works now. Thanks!